# Check if specific interface is connected?

Tags: networking

I have a shell script that checks for connection with:

```
if ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >> /dev/null 2>&1; then
```

The device will be getting 3G but I still want my code to trigger when 3G is connected but not ether-net or wifi.

I have interfaces `wlo1` and `eth1` how can I check if these specific interfaces are connected to the internet?

Comment: You can specify an interface with your ping command with -I

Comment: @RamanSailopal it can be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample script to check the status of your interfaces thought the `ping` command , using the `-I` option recommanded by [@Raman Sailopal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/244045/raman-sailopal) on his comment:

```
for i in $( ls /sys/class/net )
do 
    ping -c1 -I $i 8.8.8.8 >> /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo Your $i interface is connected   
else
    echo Your $i interface is disconnected    
    fi
done
```